# Batman Arkham City third hostage puzzle

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm at the third hostage's location. The first parts of the puzzle were quite easy, but now I'm at the part where I need to use the Electrical Charger somehow (since there are three electromagnets).

I tried shooting the magnets in several combinations and nothing seems to happen. After messing around for a few minutes I decided to look the puzzle up on the internet. I found this guide: http://guides.gamepressure.com/batmanarkhamcity/guide.asp?ID=12645 It states (at the 11th row of images)

> Prepare the Electrical Charge, as you will be using it to solve this puzzle. Start off by shooting at the left electromagnet #1 to move the steel platform left #2.

When I do that the steel box doesn't move to the left... Am I missing something here? Maybe something PS3 related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoot the electromagnet (EM) on the right with attraction to lift the box, Then shoot the EM on the left with attraction to draw the box to the left. Shoot the EM on the left with repulsion to move the box to the center, then shoot the center EM with repulsion to push the box over to the pressure plate.

Here is a video. Your answer is at the 4:55 mark:

Comment: Thanks! I never noticed that you could either use attraction or repulsion. I thought you could just charge stuff. This will also help me to solve some Riddler trophy puzzles :-)